# Не очищать div после вставки в него html(data)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт ajax обработки и отправки данных в бд без перезагрузки страницы. Результат выводится в div с id=comments.

Но если остаться на странице после добавления комментария и добавить еще один, то новый комментарий заменяет старый. Как сделать так, чтобы они не замещали друг друга, а размещались вместе?

```
<script>

    var clickedButtonValue;

    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        clickedButtonValue = $(this).val();
    });

    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#commentadd").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $(this),
                text = $form.find('textarea[id="userComment"]').val(),
                number = $form.find('input[id="num_clear"]').val(),
                url = $form.attr('action'),
                term = clickedButtonValue;

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            like: term,
            text: text,
            num_clear: number
        });

        posting.done(function( data )
        {
            /* Put the results in a div */
            $( "#comments" ).html(data);

            $("#commentadd")[0].reset();
        });
        return false;
    });



</script>
```

Comment: Нет необходимости в `return false;` после вызова `event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#comments").append($(data));
```

Comment: Спасибо еще раз :)